# vue router push() inside an async method only changes the url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have added a fake loading component that shows before the route is changed.
The loading component has to wait for a sec, therefore the method has to be asynchronous.

However, since then, the `router.push()` method started to only change the url and not the component that matches it. This happens sporadically. Sometimes, it works, and sometimes doesn't.

App.vue,

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout || 'div'">
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
    <loading-spinner v-if="store.isRouteLoading"></loading-spinner>
  </component>
</template>
```

the `push` async method

```
const navigateToNextPage = async () => {
  await showRouteLoader()
  router.push('bank-acount-info')
}
```

package ver.

```
"vue": "^3.3.4",
"vue-router": "^4.2.1",
```

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. It obviously needs to be debugged, especially since this happens "sporadically"

Comment: Not so sporadically. I have the exact same issue. Url is changed, view is not. Create an async function. Inside, call router.push(with_any_path). call that async function from a button.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work by using `Promise.then` instead of `await`ing the `Promise`.

Try this:

```
const navigateToNextPage = async () => {
    showRouteLoader().then(() => {
        router.push('bank-acount-info')
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's been months since I posted this question. I have to say that the problem I faced only happened when I was in the dev mode. Have you built the bundle in production mode and faced the same issue?

Comment: Will have to verify. Seems cumbersome though, having to build it in order to be able to see the flow locally.

Comment: yes I know. it is a very weird and annoying issue.